# Not able to in initiating x11, java handling error

Tags: java, x11

I have a Solaris-10 non global zone. I am using MobaXterm. I login on box with root and then "su - caddrd" and then "/usr/local/bin/sudo -u cadwebppc /cad/envs/qa-cm/cadwccDomain/ucm/cs/bin/UserAdmin". This is supposed to open a GUI console, but it is failing and I am not able to figure out. Can somebody help on this ?

It gives me error -

> No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Update - I am refining this question more. I am able to run xclock via root, via caddrd and via cadwebppc also. But when I am using it with sudo, it is giving error. So it seems something like, having issue with passing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set DISPLAY variable. If you are on the main display this command should do:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: No luck with this. I tried to match it with root login. On root, I am able to run /usr/openwin/bin/xclock and see a clock.    root@prod-appstess:/# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
root@prod-appstess:/# su - caddrd

-bash-3.2$ export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
-bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/sudo -u cadwebppc /cad/envs/qa-cm/cadwccDomain/ucm/cs/bin/UserAdmin
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X connection to localhost:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
-bash-3.2$

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be helpful:
http://www.snapdba.com/2013/02/ssh-x-11-forwarding-and-magic-cookies/

When switching to my oracle user (or in your case caddrd) the X11 forwarding information is lost. You can use xauth to copy it to the user's .Xauthority file

So, as root do:

> echo xauth add `xauth list ${DISPLAY#localhost}`

copy this command, sudo to your user and execute this command there.